# Nested map of slices does not work inside a function

Tags: arrays, go, nested, maps, slice

I'm trying to create a map of slices and I have the following code that works.

```
StringMap := map[string][]string{
    "numbers": []string{"1", "2"},
    "programs": []string{"red"},
}
```

But if I put it inside this function:

```
func RenderContents(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter) {
    var page Model.Page = Model.Page {
        TemplateFilename: "template.html",
        StringMap := map[string][]string{
           "numbers": []string{"1", "2"},
           "programs": []string{"red"},
        }
    }
}
```

**I get the following errors:** 
syntax error: unexpected :=, expecting comma or }
extra expression in var declaration
syntax error: unexpected : at end of statement

I'm a newbie to Go so not sure if there's an obvious answer, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a missing comma at the end of `StringMap` declaration. Also, you are using `:=` for `StringMap` initialization. It should be `:` since the initialization is for a map key:

```
func RenderContents(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter) {
    var page Model.Page = Model.Page {
        TemplateFilename: "template.html",
        StringMap: map[string][]string{
           "numbers": []string{"1", "2"},
           "programs": []string{"red"},
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it although I'm still generating the same 3 errors :(

Comment: Awesome, it kinda works now just one more error: cannot use map[string][]string literal (type map[string][]string) as type map[string]string in field value. Do I need to change the typing of the map?

Comment: What's your `Model.Page` type? If in that you have `StringMap` as `map[string]string` then you'll have to change it to `map[string][]string`

Comment: Ah yes, solved! That was my problem, changed it and now it works. Thanks abhink.